# How can I add a declaration file for an unresolved module in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an intentionally unresolved module corresponding in a JS file (it's a Webpack alias).

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved */
import messages from 'I18nMessages';
/* eslint-enable import/no-unresolved */
```

However, now I want to convert that file to TypeScript and it results in `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'I18nMessages' or its corresponding type declarations.`. Ok, that's expected. I added `@types/I18nMessages.d.ts`:

```
import type { MessageDescriptor } from 'react-intl';

declare module 'I18nMessages' {
  const messages: Record<string, MessageDescriptor>;
  export default messages;
}
```

But this doesn't remove the error. I am surprised because another similar file there works:

```
// @types/assets.d.ts

declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>;
  export default content;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

though in those cases TS can see the `.png`/`.svg` files themselves. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure, if you use just `i18n` library or something different, but did you try to install [`@types/i18n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/i18n)?

Comment: We use `intl` (and `react-intl` as you can see), and their types are installed. `I18nMessages` is a local module unrelated to `i18n`.

Comment: In a module file (top level import or export statements), `declare module "m" {... }` specifies an augmentation of an existing module that can be imported with the specifier `"m"`. In a script file (such as your assets), `declare module "m" {... }` specifies an ambient external module that can be imported with the specifier `"m"`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you! That was the answer, I needed to remove top-level `import` and replace by `const messages: Record<string, import('react-intl').MessageDescriptor>;`. Very non-obvious. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I proposed changing the error message in this case, let's see if they accept https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55347